# Haskell pair two cards

Tags: list, haskell

Currently I have the Cards list,Now I want to show all the possible pairs of cards in another list.
For example: `[(Card Club R2, Card Heart R3), (Card Club R2, Card Heart R4), (Card Club R2, Card Heart R5), (Card Club R2, Card Heart R6).........]`. 
The total result might be 1326 different pairs

Comment: I don't know enough about your suit and rank - but this should work: `[(c1,c2) | c1 <- allCards, c2 <- allCards, c1 /= c2]` if you have derived `Eq`

Comment: @CarstenKönig: OP's count (1326) suggests duplicate pairs (i.e. X,Y vs Y,X) should be eliminated. Could be achieved with `c1 < c2`; provided `Card` is an instance of `Ord` where no two cards are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
[ (c1, c2) | c1 <- allCards, c2 <- allCards, c1 /= c2 ]
```

But this will return 2652 pairs, as mentioned.

To restict this to 1326 pairs, either do as Zeta suggested or add `Ord`to `Card`:

```
[ (c1, c2) | c1 <- allCards, c2 <- allCards, c1 < c2 ]
```

Comment: You could draw the same card twice there, and why not draw from `allCards`? Your code would be far shorter: `[(c1,c2) | c1 <- allCards, c2 <- allCards, c1 /= c2]`

Comment: thanks, so what is the type of the new list, like [Card] is a list of individual card?

Comment: @PeiChuang Its ``[(Card, Card)]``

Comment: Note: This will give you 2652 pairs.

Comment: @Zeta yes this is true - I did not mind the 1326 - of course it's trivial to adjust this if you got `Ord` as @Ruud mentioned